# нужна помощь с кодом типа Random на java

Tags: java

Я сам осваивать джава стал недавно, так что прошу простить за может тупой или неправильный вопрос . 
Я хочу, чтоб после того, как рандомайзер мне выдал число (от 1 до 9), то взависимости от того, какое это число, запустился условный оператор, но почему то он не работает и выделяется красным. Вот тот код, который у меня на данный момент:

```
Random a = new Random();
    a.nextInt(10);
if (a == 2);
System.out.println("какой то текст 1");
if (a == 6)
System.out.println("какой то текст 2");
//и так далее
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно будет так:

```
Random a = new Random();
int i = a.nextInt(10);
if (i == 2)
    System.out.println("какой то текст 1");
if (i == 6)
    System.out.println("какой то текст 2");
```

`Random a = new Random();` только создает генератор случайных чистел, а вот вызов `a.nextInt(10);` возвращает вам случайное число, которое уже надо сравнивать

А еще у вас вот тут коварная ошибка(лишняя `;`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Даниил обращайтесь =)

Answer (score 5):

Вся соль в том, что в строке `Random a = new Random();` создается ссылка на объект класса Random, т.е. она не содержит какого либо целочисельного значения. В строке `a.nextInt(10);` вы вызываете метод класса Random, который непосредственно и возвращает целочисельное значение. Как уже написали, выше нужно создать примитив типа int, в который вы сохраните результат, и уже его подставляете в условный оператор.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых в строке

```
if (a == 2);
```

Не нужна точка с запятой, вы завершили условие без команды, что нужно делать, если условие выполняется, лучше всегда писать условный оператор с фигурными скобками, тогда и условия отделить легче, и не запутаешься с точками с запятой (их ставить не нужно, т.к. закрывающая фигурная скобка сама по себе является завершающим оператором). Условия лучше писать так

```
 if (a == 2){
 System.out.println("какой то текст 1");
 }
```

Касательно темы вопроса. Есть два пути решения проблемы
1) Объявить переменную типа int и подставлять в условие ее, вот так

```
 Random a = new Random();
 int x = a.nextInt(10);
 if (x == 2){
 System.out.println("какой то текст 1");
 }
 if (x == 6){
 System.out.println("какой то текст 2");
 }
```

2) Воспользоваться методом equals вместо "==", вот так

```
 Random a = new Random();

 if (a.equals(2)){
 System.out.println("какой то текст 1");
 }
 if (a.equals(6)){
 System.out.println("какой то текст 2");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a == 6) {
    System.out.println("some text");
}
```

Условный оператор выглядит так:

```
if (условие) {
    // То, что надо сделать
}
```

Также можно:

```
if (условие) {
    // 1
} else {
    // 2
}
```

А если слишком много условий, то используйте [Оператор switch, 'компактный if'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)
Также настоятельно Вам рекомендую пользоваться поисковиком, там есть очень много статей и материала, которые Вам помогут.

Comment: Не согласен с использованием switch, тем более если условий много. Мало того, что внутри каждого case нужен break, который занимает столько же места, сколько и else, но с ним можно легко запутаться и поставить не там, так еще и блок default нужно прописывать во избежание ошибок, что приводит к листанию длинного списка case условий.